# How do I use double pipes || with heredoc?

Tags: bash, psql

I am trying to accomplish a fairly simple goal: react to the possible error of a previous command with a second command. The wrench in the spokes is the need to use a heredoc syntax in the first command.

this (trivialized example) would produce the result I want to catch:

```
psql -c "select * from table_that_doesnt_exist" || echo "error"
```

except, the SQL I need to execute is multiple commands and for my circumstance, I must do this with heredocs:

```
psql << SQL
select * from good_table;
select * from table_that_doesnt_exist
SQL
```

and when trying to successfully read the stderr from this type of configuration (I've tried a million ways) I cannot seem to figure it out. These kind of methods do not work:

```
( psql << SQL
select * from good_table;
select * from table_that_doesnt_exist
SQL
) || echo "error"
```

or

```
psql << SQL || echo "error"
select * from good_table;
select * from table_that_doesnt_exist
SQL
```

Comment: Both syntaxes are fine. The issue is whether `psql` actually has a non-zero exit status if the given query fails.

Comment: It definitely should. For example, the same exact command, only using the -c flag instead of a heredoc syntax: 'psql -c "select * from table_that_doesnt_exist"' would definitely result in a non-zero exit status.

Comment: Ok, so I just figured out what the issue was very clearly. Turns out that it has to do with transactions. It seems that whenever a non "-c" syntax is used, it automatically goes into a "transactional mode" wrapping all statements in a transaction. In this mode, if there is any error, it is automatically rolled back. From psql's standpoint, that isn't an error, because the transaction was successfully rolled back. What would be a non-zero exit status would be if psql was killed mid-execution.

Comment: That actually makes a fair amount of sense - its just strange that the same logic doesn't apply in the "-c" circumstances. It's slightly inconsistent behavior that takes a lot of head-scratching to figure out.